# Laptop monitor uses a lot of bandwidth compared to external monitor

Tags: display, performance, bandwidth

My external monitor is using a lot less bandwidth compared to my laptop monitor. This happens only when I use "remote desktop connection".

When I keep scrolling down a text file at the same speed, the monitor uses 30-40kb/s while my laptop uses 400-500kb/s.

Laptop: Vaio, 1080p, 15.6 inches. 60hz
Monitor: Gateway, 1080p, 23 inches. 60hz (connected to vaio with HDMI)

Does anybody know why this happen?

** Edited **
I'm not really sure what was causing this but this was solved.

One day, I connected my laptop to a different monitor and changed the "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" in the display settings. Then right after that, the RDP session on my laptop started using a lot less bandwidth (less than 50kb/s).

Again, I don't know if this action really fixed the issue but I will just leave this memo in case somebody is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the question wrongly - it took me a while to get my head around it.   I understand that you have an RDP session viewing 2 remote sessions, one using a lot more bandwidth then the other.

In reality, the frequency and  physical size of the monitors are irrelevant, as is the connection between the monitor and the computer - as RDP does not care about any of this.

There are a number of possibilities which could explain the performance differences - one of the most likely is compression.  The text file you are scrolling is probably black on white or similar, and this can compress very well - if your RDP session is using compression.

Other differences could include the use of a reduced color map and/or color depth and not sending mouse motion events.  Also sending things like audio.

Also possible are different versions of VNC.  For example, Version 7 apparently added "Aero glass remote".  Version 10 included compression improvements including the use of H.264/AVC for better compression.  (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) article)

Comment: Thanks. The monitor was connected to the laptop with HDMI. And I opened a RDP session. If I moved the RDP screen to my monitor, it used small bandwidth (less than 50kb). If I moved it on the laptop, it used a lot of bandwidth (sometimes over 500mb).
I don't know much about computer so it's hard for me to check what you've mentioned. but Thank you so much for spending time for me.